# How to use flowbite datepicker plugin in vue 3 project composition API and typescript

Tags: typescript, datepicker, vuejs3, vite, flowbite

I am a newbie with  vue 3 and typescript and i can't find a way to make flowbite's datepicker to work on a vue 3 project using composition API and typescript in vite. The problems is that i can't find in the documentation a way to use the js for the datepicker and how tu use it in a project with the details i already described. Is it even possible? my last try was to import it in the `main.ts` with `import datepicker from "flowbite/dist/datepicker";` create a .d.ts file with declare module `"flowbite/dist/datepicker";` add this file in `tsconfig.json` with include (I also added other configurations from other stack overflow answers)

```
"include": [
    "typings.d.ts"
  ],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "strict": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "allowJs": true
  }
```

so in general what is the right way then to use a js file inside a vue 3 composition api using typescript. By the way the error in visual studio code still says Could not find a declaration file for module 'flowbite/dist/datepicker'

I tried a lot of things already but couldn't find a solution specific to this king of project not in flowbite, vue 3 site or stackoverflow or google in general as I said is it even possible to do that?

Comment: It seems that Flowbite's datepicker is not compatible with Vue 3 Composition API. I've tried it as well and it did not work. As an alternative, use `vuepic/vue-datepicker`